# Path problems in a Vite/Vue3/Laravel webapp

Tags: laravel, path, vuejs3, vite

I'm having problems with setting up the correct paths for my Vue3/Vite/Laravel web app, hosted via a cPanel interface.

In my development machine, the folder structure is...

```
|
|-app
|-bootstrap
|-config
|-node_modules
|-public
    -build
        -assets
    -constants
    -images
|-resources
    -components
    -css
    -i18n
    -js
    -views
|-routes
|-storage
|-vendor
```

In cPanel, the folder structure is similar, albeit nested two levels down:

```
|-home
    -public_html
        -app
        :
        :
        -vendor
```

The related paths in my app.js are:

```
import Home from '@/components/pages/Home.vue'
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL),
    routes: [
        { path: '/', name: 'home', component: Home },
        { path: '/training', name: 'training', component: Training },
        { path: '/contacts', name: 'Contacts', component: () => import('../components/pages/Contacts.vue') },
        { path: '/legal', name: 'Legal', component: () => import('../components/pages/Legal.vue') },
        { path: '/search', name: 'Search', component: () => import('../components/pages/Search.vue') },
    ]
});
```

My vite.config.js file is:

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'
import { resolve, dirname } from 'node:path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import Components from 'unplugin-vue-components/vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import VueI18nPlugin from '@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n/vite'
import pluginRewriteAll from 'vite-plugin-rewrite-all';


export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    laravel({
        input: 'resources/js/app.js',
        refresh: true,
    }),
    pluginRewriteAll(),
    VueI18nPlugin({
        runtimeOnly: false, //https://lokalise.com/blog/vue-i18n/
        include: resolve(dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)), './resources/locales/**'),
        strictMessage: false
      }),
    Components({
      resolvers: [

      ],
    }),
  ],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./resources', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
})
```

The base url for Vite - stored in .env - is VITE_BASE_URL = '/'

When I view the site ('mysitename.co.nz'), nothing is loaded, with 404's (e.g. from 'mysitename.co.nz/build/assets/app-12345.js').  The 'not found' files are present, but only discoverable via 'mysitename.co.nz/**public**/build/assets/app-12345.js'

If I change Vite's base url to '/public', the default home page opens with the expected images, but content that comes from a database call e.g. 'mysitename.co.nz/home/1' generates a 404.  I've manually checked that call using 'mysitename.co.nz/**public**/home/1' and it returns the data I expect.

Where are the path changes that need to be made to get my site running?